# C# method selection chooses object instead of IEnumerable<object> when passing a primitive type collection

Tags: c#

I have an object with two add methods:

`public void Add(string keyName, object value)`

`public void Add(string keyName, IEnumerable<object> values)`

If you call it and provide an object, it calls the first one. If you provide an IEnumerable it calls the second one. However if you provide an IEnumerable of a primative type, it calls the first one.

Is there a way to make c# choose the 2nd method and box it rather than treat the array as an object?

If not I guess I will put a check in the first add method to see if it's a primitive type ienumerable and force it to call the second method.

Comment: you are forgetting that anything can be casted to `object` and that's what happening here

Comment: So this looks like a really easy question in which to add a self-contained example. In fact, the question is conspicuous by its absence.

Comment: "If not I guess I will put a check in the first add method to see if it's a primitive type ienumerable and force it to call the second method." -- How exactly do you hope to do this? `IEnumerable<int>` isn't convertible to `IEnumerable<object>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use generics for this. If you change the second method to:

```
public void Add<T>(string keyName, IEnumerable<T> values)
{

}
```

Then if it is any kind of `IEnumerable<T>` (eg `IEnumerable<int>`) then it will use the generic method.

It is worth noting that `IEnumerable<T>` is not exactly the same as `IEnumerable<object>` so if you *need* it to be an `IEnumerable<object>` you would need something like `IEnumerable<object> obList = values.Cast<object>();`

Comment: Ah I see, that does make more sense. Thanks.

Comment: Unless I'm going nuts it is calling that method even when I am just passing in an ordinary string. How is that even possible. It hits a breakpoint on the first line, and if I do values.GetType() it is a type of "String"... it should be hitting the other method, and surely a string is not `IEnumerable<T>`!?

Comment: Hmmm.... Yes, that will be because string implements `IEnumerable<char>` I guess making it a better match for the second method than the first... I'm not quite sure how to get around that (apart from stopping using objects or special casing it (eg checking if `values.GetType()==typeof(string)`).

Comment: I've added another method that takes a `string`, I can't think of any other instances that would confuse a developer calling the add method. `object` just lets people call it with things that can be sensibly ToString'd. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

To add to @Chris answer and explain why it does not work with your way. `IEnumerable<T>` defined like this:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T>
```

Where `out` means type `T` is covariant, which in turn means you can use child type in it's place. In your case it means you can use any type that inherits from `object` where `IEnumerable<object>` is expected, such as `IEnumerable<string>`. BUT those covariance modifiers (out\in) do not work with value types (structs). That means `IEnumerable<string>` is convertible to `IEnumerable<object>` but `IEnumerable<int>` does not. So compiler cannot chose second overload because it will just not compile.

The right way to solve that as already been answered is to use generics (you can also explicitly cast `IEnumerable<int>` with `en.Cast<object>()`).

Comment: Good job on the extra context. I did already add the Cast into my answer as well (presumably after you first read my answer while you were writing yours).

Comment: Many thanks for the extra information, it is good to understand why this occurred.